# Custom android tabs with different tab width

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs

Is there a way to create Android tabs with images where:

- the tab width is not equal for all tabs?
- the tabs are NOT scrollable to the sides (meaning, not like Google play)

Can I do this with an Android component? Or even with Actionbar tabs?[image] (not create a custom view)

See example image.